# Ubuntu 17.10 - what program to use for window position memory (maximized, X,Y positions)

Tags: windows, window-placement

CompizConfig doesn't seem to work anymore.

I used ccsm to open terminal at a default size 80x20 and at (X100, Y1000) ~ is there an alernative to set default windows placement properties than ccsm? Also, for example, I used to have ccsm open Adobe Brackets maximized..

Comment: @qorka Please [edit] your question to add info.

Comment: I've seen a few recommendations of

gnome-terminal --geometry=WidthxHeight+Xposition+Yposition

The issue is opening with Ctrl + Alt + T to a specific window size and position, which originally you could modify with ccsm. The command above is not a permanent setting, like with ccsm.